# How to use direct264 in Directshow?

Tags: windows, directshow, x264

I am finding a h264 (x264) directshow filter for my application and i found project direct264 here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/direct264

When can see dump.ax from binary package but when i load it to GraphStudioNext (or try to register it by using regsvr32) i see error:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tientrieu.net](http://tientrieu.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/direct264_load_error.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their dump.ax has nothing to do with Windows SDK [Dump Filter Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388553). It's not a COM DLL, it does not host filters in proper way - it instead does its own thing. The messages on provided screenshots are expected behavior.